# How to show button in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am making a quiz game and I was wondering how I can make the proceed button appear. it goes from the user typing the right answer, displaying a nice good jobs sort of message, then at the same time a button pops up saying that the user can proceed. could someone help?

[Image Of The Code Click Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LdpqW.png)

Comment: Please actually put the code in your question instead of an image, that way we can copy paste and help you. :-)

Comment: Also, what's with the spacing in the code? You could an elephant between those lines!

Comment: I'm sorry :( @ChrisL

Answer (score 0):

Use these methods -

```
    function show_button(id){
    document.getElementById(id).style.display = "block";

}

function hide_button (id){

    document.getElementById(id).style.display = "none";
}
```

if the user enters the correct answer then call

```
hide_button(id of the html element);
```

you can display messages informing that user had entered the correct answer or not by making use of javascript and accessing the CSS stuff with javascript.

```
 document.getElementById(id).style returns you a css object.
```

you can modify CSS (style, margin, padding, color) of the HTML elements using javascipt to create a dynamic webpage.

Comment: Thank you so much I will try that tommorow :D

Comment: Sure! and let me know about it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use jquery the code is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var input = ("#the.id.of.your.input").val();
    var result = "The result";
    if(input == result){
        $("#id.of.your.button").fadeIn();
        // or: ("#id.of.your.button").show();
    }
});
```